# Why does't my popup window work in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

[image]I created a popup window using CSS. It is working fine in google chrome; however, it is not displaying in Safari as expected. Above photo is in Safari and the bottom photo is in chrome.

[image]

The following code is what I used to create the popup window:

```
.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 620px;
  max-width: 900px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -200%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -200%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -200%);

  -webkit-transition: transform 500ms ease-out;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-out;
}
.modal:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  display: none;

  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

And this following code is what I used to create my header

```
.box {
  position: fixed;
  top:0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  z-index: 900;
}
```

Does anyone have an explanation why in chrome everything looks fine, but in safari not ?
Thanks

Comment: Give the modal larger z-index than the header

Comment: I tried, still does not work